# Is it compulsory to use the abstract class as the root class in Java?

Tags: java, class, abstract, extends

Is it compulsory to use the abstract class as the root class in Java? In other words, can I extends an normal class to create a derived abstract class?

Comment: All classes extend Object which is not abstract.

Answer (score 4):

Yes to your second question.  Try it and see.  Your code will compile.

Think about it this way: Every class already extends the concrete class `Object`, yet you can still make your own classes that are abstract.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an `abstract` class extend a non `abstract` class

```
public static class Parent /* extends Object */ {}

public static abstract class Child extends Parent {}
```

(the `static` here is for copy-paste test)

This means that you will need a 3rd level class that extends `Child` to make use of the `Child` abstract methods, if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend abstract and non abstract non final classes. Take a look at Object.java. This is not Abstract and is the root of all objects in java. You cannot extend a final class as per the java spec. See 8.1.1.2. final Classes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html)